# What is the probe that absorbs at 450nm in the presence of NADH in this assay?

Tags: biochemistry, assay-development

The colorimetric assays by [Biovision](http://www.biovision.com/manuals/K789.pdf?osCsid=4dh8peelaulm53p8dr9qhgoj11) and [Sigma Aldrich](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/content/dam/sigma-aldrich/docs/Sigma/Bulletin/1/mak082bul.pdf) seem to utilise a probe that binds to or reacts with NADH in order to cause absorbance at 450nm which can then be quantified by a spectrophotometer.

What is the chemical basis of this reaction?

Comment: I don't think they would reveal it but perhaps the substrate is [this](http://www.google.com/patents/WO2014130834A1?cl=en) molecule.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thanks! You should convert that to an answer.

Comment: I am not sure if that is the same compound.

Comment: They will most likely not reveal which substance they are using. Most likely it is something which is oxidized by NADH and then gives a blue color.

Comment: @Chris it absorbs 450nm it may emit a longer wavelength.

Comment: @MarchHo the substrate can also be Dansyl aminoacetaldehyde ([See here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7742535)). But Sigma does not mention a fluorimetric assay and DAAA absorbs at a lower wavelength; so can't really comment on what that substrate can be.

Comment: This is not an answer, but you don't need the mysterious probe to measure NADH production. NADH absorbs at 340nm (while NAD+ is flat at 340nm) and A340 is measured in many well-documented colorimetric (coupled) kinase assays before any kinase assay kit was in the market.

Comment: @SYK Thanks for the note, but I am aware of it (and am actually using it in some of my experiments). I was just curious on the chemical nature of this assay.